# Standardize dataset with high outliers

Tags: data-transformation, outliers, standardization

Is there a better way to standardize a dataset with outliers than to normalized value (z-score) based on the mean and standard deviation? I am using the Excel STANDARDIZE function.

I have two datasets with huge outliers and I cannot remove them. Here is a summary of one of them.

Min. value: 0.29
Mean: 402,1
SD: 2222,89
Max. value: 23793

As can be noticed, I have a big range of values and all the lower values stay "hidden" by the highest ones.

What is the best way to standardize this dataset?

[image]

Comment: Try making a boxplot out of the logarithm of these data.

Comment: Looks much better. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked, Patricia. The only caveat with this approach is if some of your data are going to be exactly 0, we have to think a little bit about how to handle it.

Comment: What is your goal? Plotting the data? Analyzing it? Doing a hypothesis test? Something else?

Comment: My goals are plotting and then analyzing these data with linear models. I just noticed that there are two zeros at the data set now.

Comment: @PatriciaNunes the quick and dirty solution is to increment each observation by 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This data would be better visualised (and quite possibly analysed as well) with a transformation.

A log transformation is usually a good solution for right-skewed data such as this. If you have zeroes in there, a square root transformation should work well instead (it's best to avoid adding a constant before taking the log, even though that practice is common). And if you have negative values as well, try a cube root transformation.

EDIT: see Nick Cox's comment below for some helpful additional thoughts.

Comment: This (+1). I used to be sceptical about. even slightly hostile to. log(1 + y) as too _ad hoc_ but so long as it is realised what it does and does not do. it can be helpful, at least for visualization.  The so-called neglog sign(y) * log(1 + abs(y)) and its sister under the skin asinh() can cope well with any mix of negative, zero, and positive. Square root and cube root can be useful as hinted. With most software cube rooting a negative number will not work unless you carefully separate the calculation using sign(y) * abs(y)^(1/3).

Comment: @NickCox Thanks, I generally agree and these are all useful tips. Though I have seen problems arise with log(y + constant) because people default to the constant being 1; that specific value doesn't always make sense, of course.

Comment: Pitfalls are everywhere dense, as Besicovitch said in a different context. Particularly awful is a presumption that log(y + smidgen) is very close to log y, which naturally is true for large y but not at all for y near zero. Also often awful is basing the constant on the current dataset. If the variable in question is the outcome or response, then using a logarithmic link avoids the question neatly.

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you for the discussion and suggestions. I am considering all of them.

Answer (score 1):

if it is one category of data then okay. Otherwise, you will use some robust statistics to overcome the problem like median, quartiles etc. Z-score will not be suitable as it is based on deviation from the mean.

Comment: I am not sure if you are hinting at this but (value $-$ median) / IQR is even worse as a standardization measure in the presence of major skewness and/or outliers.